# sum aggregate function with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

my whole code is here:

```
    select top (@selectCount) w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber, w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.userId,  q.bidedItem, SUM(q.bidCount) as sumOfBids, sum(w.codesLeft + q.bidCount) as 'allCode'
from geopl_kubetiAuct.secondWeekBids as q 
join geopl_kubetiAuct.Users w on q.userId = w.Id
where q.bidedItem = @Prize 
group by w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber, w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.bidedItem, q.userId
order by sumOfBids desc
```

I have problem with

```
sum(w.codesLeft + q.bidCount) as 'allCode'
```

If q.bidCount is more than 1 it iterates over this w.codesLeft and q.bidCount as many bids are there. for example if there are 2 bids result will

> 2 + 5 + 2 + 10
>   (codesLeft is 2, first bid is 5 and second is 10)

How can I improve that?

AllCode must return **(2+5+10)**

Comment: @SMA that allCode return (2+5+10)

Comment: Your SQL doesn't have the expression `sum(w.codesLeft + q.bidCount)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sry it was my bad. I was trying different things and than copy that. actually it has it edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that `w.codesLeft` appears on each row before the `group by`.  It gets a separate value on this intermediate set of data, so when you sum it, you get the wrong value.

The solution is to use `max(w.codesLeft)` rather than just `codesLeft`.

```
select top (@selectCount) w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber,
        w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.userId, q.bidedItem,
        SUM(q.bidCount) as sumOfBids,
        (max(w.codesLeft) + sum(q.bidCount)) as allCode
from geopl_kubetiAuct.secondWeekBids q join
     geopl_kubetiAuct.Users w
     on q.userId = w.Id
where q.bidedItem = @Prize 
group by w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber,
         w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.bidedItem, q.userId
order by sumOfBids desc;
```

However, this assumes that your query was originally `sum(w.codesLeft + q.bidCount)` -- without the `sum()` you would get an error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You must right this:
`(sum(w.codesLeft) + sum(q.bidCount)) as 'allCode'`

Because in sum operator you only write one column.
For more info about `Sum` operator go to this msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).